# Liberty jmsQueueConnectionFactory set createConnection() timeout

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, websphere-liberty

in my application I check if my MQ connection is available with the method `javax.jms.ConnectionFactory.createConnection()` of the connection factory.

```
connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
```

Currently the MQ firewall is blocked so the connection is not established and I get a `com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: MQJCA1011: Failed to allocate a JMS connection`.

The problem I have, is, that the method has a running time at around 2 minutes.
I would like to set this to a much lower value. The method has no parameter to set a timeout, so I think it should be set on the application server.

I'm running Liberty 18.0.0.1.

My `server.xml` looks like this:

```
    <jmsQueueConnectionFactory id="myConnectionFactory"
            jndiName="myJNDI" connectionManagerRef="ConMgr0">
            <properties.wmqJms transportType="CLIENT" hostName="x.x.x.x"
        port="1234" channel="myChannel" queueManager="myQmanager"
        userName="myUSER" password="myPW" />
    </jmsQueueConnectionFactory>
    <connectionManager id="ConMgr0" maxPoolSize="10"
            agedTimeout="0s" connectionTimeout="10s"/>
```

However, the option `connectionTimeout` for the **connection manager** does not change this behavior (restarted Liberty after saving values). Even if I did not set it, the default value would be 30s what is clearly less than 2 minutes : )

Is there some other configuration I am missing here?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

While I can't tell you how to solve the problem, I can explain why what you tried doesn't work.  The connectionManager element configures the connection pool, and its connectionTimeout is a timeout on obtaining a pooled connection, not a timeout on establishment of a new connection.  In order to control the timeout for a new connection to be established, you would need a property on properties.wmqJms (it doesn't appear that any exists for this), but even then it wouldn't help you because you don't know whether the connection you get back is going to be a newly established connection or a pooled connection.

Comment: Ok, but I would have thought that even for the first connection the factory looks into the connection manager for a pooled connection, creates a new one if empty and then this configuration would apply. And for me it does not matter if it is a pooled one or not, as long as my check returns a connection or error in a reasonable time.

Comment: It doesn't quite work that way. The connection manager and the resource adapter that establishes the connections are two different entities with different implementations and different config settings.  A timeout specified on the connectionManager can only apply to the time the connectionManager itself waits, either for an available pooled connection or for an open spot in the pool that allows for a new connection to be created.  In the case of the initial connection, the pool is empty, it does not wait at all and immediately asks the resource adapter to establish a connection.  ...continued

Comment: The connectionManager cannot possibly have built-in knowledge of all the vendor-specific ways of setting timeouts on the different resource adapters that can be plugged in. Nor is there any standard way to reliably interrupt connection establishment upon which it could build its own timeout mechanism on behalf of resource adapters. As is stands currently, any implementation of timeouts on connection establishment is left to each resource adapter to define its own vendor specific mechanisms.